# Binary tree produce Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

I'm new to C and want to get started by coding a simple binary tree. There are problems in both the push and traverse functions but it's been two days me figuring out the program. When I compiles and execute the program it shows segmentation fault. The code is given below and any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct Node
{
  struct Node* right;
  struct Node* left;
  int* value;
} Node;

Node* init()
{
  Node* t = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
  t->left = NULL;
  t->right = NULL;
  t->value = NULL;
  return t;
}

int traverse(Node* tree)
{
  printf("value : %d\n", *(tree->value));
  if (tree->left != NULL) {
    traverse(tree->left);
  } else if (tree->right != NULL){
    traverse(tree->right);
  }
}

void push(Node* n, int val)
{
  if (n->value == NULL)
  {
    *(n->value) = val;
  } else if (n->left == NULL && val < *(n->value)) {
    n->left = init();
    push(n->left, val);
  } else if (n->right == NULL && val > *(n->value)) {
    n->right = init();
    push(n->right, val);
  }
} 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  Node* tree = init();

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
  {
    int val = rand() % 10;
    push(tree, val);
    printf("%d\n", val);
  }

  traverse(tree);
  printf("%s\n", "End Of Program!");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int* value;` is a questionable choice unless this linked list is intended to hold dynamic arrays of `int`s. `int value;` Is more likely what you need.

Comment: does the `traverse` function should return `int`? or just `void` might be better

Comment: it should but for debugging purpose I didn't bother

Comment: btw is NULL a pointer in C

Comment: `NULL` is a *null pointer constant*. Technically, it might be `0` or `((void *) 0)` or something equivalent to one of those. You should not rely on it having a particular form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never allocate space for value.  Change the definition to an integer.

```
typedef struct Node
{
  struct Node* right;
  struct Node* left;
  int value;
} Node;
```

and then

```
n->value = val;
```

and

```
printf("value : %d\n", tree->value);
```

Comment: but then how to i do comparison to see if it null value or not

Comment: @Syed.bcc In this case, you wouldn't compare it to a null value. It should be defaulted to something outside the range of what you want to be valid values for the tree; i.e. you want positive uints, default it to -1

Answer (score 1):

The `value` member of the `Node` type is never set to any value other than `NULL`. Since its value is a null pointer, using the statement `*(n->value) = val;` is improper; it attempts to dereference the null pointer.

If you want `value` to point to an `int`, you must allocate memory for an `int` and set `value` to the address of that memory. If you want `value` to be an `int`, you must change its declaration, and the code that uses it.